# Which version of Scala Eclipse plugin should I use?

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-indigo, scala-ide

On the Scala download page two versions of Scala Eclipse plugina are offered, 2.10.x & 2.9.x :

http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html

[image]

Which version of Scala should I use for Eclipse Indigo 2.10.x or 2.9.x ? What is the difference between each version ?

Comment: Which version of scala are you going to use? Take corresponding plugin version.

Comment: It depends on the type of development you wish to do. If your using frameworks, other dependencies, the platform you can use them on... and lots more. Add these details and get a good answer.

Comment: What I'm interested in is the level of backward compatability. Does downloading the 2.10 version not include support for 2.9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If starting a new project, just download 2.10.x, which is current. 2.9.x is for backwards compatibility.

I recommend my project [skeleton](http://github.com/fractal/skeleton) to get started with SBT + Eclipse